# Preimage of submanifold under an embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose we have two smooth manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ and a smooth
map $i:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ that is an embedding of $M_1$ into
$M_2$. Moreover we have another submanifold $N \subset M_2$ that has a
non empty intersection with the embedding $i(M_1)$. Then,in what situation is the
preimage set $i^{-1}(N)$ a submanifold of $M_1$?

Or in other words, what do we have to assume so that the preimage set is a submanifold?

Comment: Do you mean "what do we have to assume **so** that the preimage set is a submanifold"? I assume so, but would just like to check.

Comment: Yes. I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hypothesis that works is that $N$ is transverse to the image of $i$, but this is not a necessary condition. For example, the preimage under the inclusion of the $x$ axis into $\mathbb R^2$ of the parabola $\{(t,t^2):t\in\mathbb R\}$ is a submanifold...

Comment: Unfortunately the nice transversal-property is not applicable in my situation. (That is why I'm asking.) But I guess there is no other general condition and I have to do it "by hand".

Comment: @Mark, you should probably explain what your situation is :)

Comment: That will not work.

Comment: So instead, the idea is to have people shot in the dark until they hit the hidden target. Now *that* will work!

Comment: The manifolds I have in mind are images of Weil functors and hence are fibered, too.